# How can I translate strings in Blazor components and App.razor?

Tags: .net-core, localization, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I want to localize strings of shared components like "NavMenu.razor" or the "App.razor" page.

I managed to translate content in my pages as described in the [general .NET Core instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  and the more [specific Blazor documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

- Create a resource file with the right name (e.g. PageName.de.resx).
- Inject localizer into Razor page with `@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<PageName> _l10n`.
- Translate text inside the page with `_l10n["Product name"]` which gets translated correctly to "Produktname".

This approach did not work for neither "NavMenu.razor" nor "App.razor".

Please note: I use MatNavMenu from the MatBlazor UI lib for main navigation.

I cannot find it documented anywhere. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try  ... IStringLocalizer<App> and use App.resx . You can put the injection in _imports that way and its available to all components. I can confirm it works in App.razor that way

Comment: That should work right? Strangely, I tried something similar before. Tried again with your instructions. No luck.

Comment: If I get the time ill post a repo with it demonstrated. I cant really post the project I am looking  at ...

Comment: I just posted a repo for you. Forgive the translations I used a web service. I just changed my language on edge or chrome and reloaded the page to see the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easy:

- Install Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
- in programs.cs

  ```
  builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
  builder.Services.AddScoped<IStringLocalizer<App>,StringLocalizer<App>>();
  ```
- Create a Resources folder in your client project. Add a resx file to
  that for instance App.resx this will be your default resources. Then
  add more files for each language you wish to support. App.fr.resx
  App.es.resx ect.

[image]

Then in a component inject

```
    @inject IStringLocalizer<App> L
    
    @L["YourText"]
```

The localizer will use browsers language and look in, in my case, App.en-AU.resx, App.en.resx, App.resx order for the key. If not found it will use "YourText"

Here is a blazor WASM project [repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/BlazorLocalisation)

Comment: Thanks. It helped. I had made a stupid mistake. I put "App.resx" file into the "pages" subdirectory and ... BÄM! Your example helped me solve this. I can put the strings for components into this app resource file, too, and it works.

Comment: Is there anyone who know if the resx-files can be put in a seperate class lib and set the "options.resourcePath"... Beeing trying but does not seem to work :-(

Comment: Just a note that the call to `AddLocalization` already registers `IStringLocalizer` with dependency injection for you, so you don't need to call it. [Here is the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Localization/Localization/src/LocalizationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L65).