# Translate Blazor application dynamically?

Tags: localization, blazor, translation, blazor-server-side

I want to translate my Blazor application. However, everywhere I look you need to have resource files with the corresponding language, and surround every word on the page with something like this: `@localizer["Date of birth"]` to make them match in my resource files.

My application, however, can have dynamic content that the users supply, so I can never predict what I will need to translate.
Are there other ways to translate the application, that are able to translate the application dynamically?

Thanks in advance!

(This answer elaborates more on the Localization extension (which is not what I'm looking for): [How can I translate strings in Blazor components and App.razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614887/how-can-i-translate-strings-in-blazor-components-and-app-razor))

Comment: No, I wouldn't bother with any code geared toward hand-organizing translated content using resource files.  Instead, use a SQL database to store translations of a given text by locale.  Azure has Microsoft's version of a translate API that is very cheap and ultra fast.  Google's is good as well.  Chat-GPT's is quite good, but in my experience because it's slower it's not the best tool for the job of translation.  So whenever a page is loading texts, you first check your database for an exisitng translation in a person's locale, and if it's missing, you run the original text through translate.

Comment: Azure Translate, btw is free up to 2M characters / month, roughly the length of the Bible.  So unless you are running a truly massive enterprise, you can fire it up right now and start translating your little heart out. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator/